# Saving and Reading UserState in Botframework v4

Tags: node.js, botframework

Hello I'm having a hard time dealing with UserStates in MSBF

Here's the setup of the dialogBot.ts

```
export class DialogBot extends ActivityHandler {
private conversationState: BotState;
private userState: BotState;
private dialog: Dialog;
private dialogState: StatePropertyAccessor<DialogState>;

/**
 *
 * @param {BotState} conversationState
 * @param {BotState} userState
 * @param {Dialog} dialog
 */
constructor(
    conversationState: BotState,
    userState: BotState,
    dialog: Dialog
) {
    super();
    if (!conversationState) {
        throw new Error(
            '[DialogBot]: Missing parameter. conversationState is required'
        );
    }
    if (!userState) {
        throw new Error('[DialogBot]: Missing parameter. userState is required');
    }
    if (!dialog) {
        throw new Error('[DialogBot]: Missing parameter. dialog is required');
    }

    this.conversationState = conversationState as ConversationState;
    this.userState = userState as UserState;
    this.dialog = dialog;
    this.dialogState =
        this.conversationState.createProperty<DialogState>('DialogState');

    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
        console.log('Running dialog with Message Activity.');

        // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
        await (this.dialog as MainDialog).run(context, this.dialogState);

        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
    });

    this.onDialog(async (context, next) => {
        // Save any state changes. The load happened during the execution of the Dialog.
        await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, false);
        await this.userState.saveChanges(context, false);

        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
    });
}
```

}

In the MainDialog.ts I'm fetching a user from the database based on the userID passed on  and if it fetches anything it should be saved in the UserState.

**mainDialog.ts**

```
export class MainDialog extends CancelAndHelpDialog {
private userProfileAccessor: StatePropertyAccessor<any>;
userState: UserState;

constructor(
    bookingDialog: BookingDialog,
    userState: UserState,
    conversationState: ConversationState
) {
    super('MainDialog');

    // DECLARE DIALOGS HERE
    const createJobOrderDialog = new CreateJobOrderDialog(
        'createJobOrderDialog'
    );
    const checkJobOrderStatusDialog = new CheckJobOrderStatusDialog(
        'checkJobOrderStatusDialog'
    );
    const accountSetupDialog = new AccountSetupDialog(
        'accountSetupDialog',
        userState
    );

    this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty('userProfile');

    this.userState = userState;

    // Define the main dialog and its related components.
    // This is a sample "book a flight" dialog.
    this.addDialog(new TextPrompt('TextPrompt'));

    this.addDialog(bookingDialog);
    this.addDialog(createJobOrderDialog);
    this.addDialog(checkJobOrderStatusDialog);
    this.addDialog(accountSetupDialog);

    this.addDialog(
        new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.accountSetupStep.bind(this),
            this.introStep.bind(this),
            this.actStep.bind(this),
            this.finalStep.bind(this)
        ])
    );

    this.initialDialogId = MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
}

/**
 * The run method handles the incoming activity (in the form of a DialogContext) and passes it through the dialog system.
 * If no dialog is active, it will start the default dialog.
 * @param {TurnContext} context
 */
public async run(
    context: TurnContext,
    accessor: StatePropertyAccessor<DialogState>
) {
    const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
    dialogSet.add(this);

    const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(context);
    const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
    if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
        await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
    }
}

private async accountSetupStep(
    stepContext: WaterfallStepContext
): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {
    const userProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(
        stepContext.context,
        {}
    );

    stepContext.context.activity.from.id = '*******************';

    userProfile.isHandover = false;
    await this.userProfileAccessor.set(stepContext.context, userProfile);
    // await this.userState.saveChanges(stepContext.context, true);

    const result = await userService.getUser(
        stepContext.context.activity.from.id
    );
    console.log(result);

    if (Object.keys(result).length === 0) {
        return await stepContext.beginDialog('accountSetupDialog');
    } else {
        userProfile.user = result;
        await this.userProfileAccessor.set(stepContext.context, userProfile);
        // await this.userState.saveChanges(stepContext.context, true);

        return await stepContext.next();
    }
}
private async introStep(
    stepContext: WaterfallStepContext
): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {
    const userProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(
        stepContext.context,
        {}
    );
    console.log('INTRO STEP USERPROFILE', userProfile);
    await stepContext.context.sendActivities([
        {
            type: 'message',
            text: `Hi ${userProfile.user.first_name}, welcome to Podmachine. Let us take care of the dirty stuff so you can sound like a Pro!`
        },
        {
            type: 'typing'
        },
        { type: 'delay', value: 1000 },
        {
            type: 'message',
            text: 'To start, you need to submit a job order.'
        },
        {
            type: 'typing'
        },
        { type: 'delay', value: 1000 },
        {
            type: 'message',
            text: `So what's a job order? It's basically sending a request to edit (1) one raw episode audio file to Podmachine team. We'll handle the rest. `
        },
        {
            type: 'typing'
        },
        { type: 'delay', value: 1000 },
        {
            type: 'message',
            text: `Since you're part of the early access users (Yay!), you're entitled to (1) one free job order / edit. Go ahead and click "Create New Job order."`
        },
        {
            type: 'typing'
        },
        { type: 'delay', value: 1000 }
    ]);
    const messageText = (stepContext.options as any).restartMsg
        ? (stepContext.options as any).restartMsg
        : `Please take note that once you submit your job order, Podmachine team will review it first. Make sure all the details you put in your job order are correct. It will be our basis when we do the edits. Thank you!`;
    const promptMessage = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(
        [
            'Create New Job Order',
            'Check Status',
            'Chat with Team',
            'Subscribe Now'
        ],
        messageText
    );
    return await stepContext.prompt('TextPrompt', {
        prompt: promptMessage
    });
}

/**
 * Second step in the waterall.  This will use LUIS to attempt to extract the origin, destination and travel dates.
 * Then, it hands off to the bookingDialog child dialog to collect any remaining details.
 */
private async actStep(
    stepContext: WaterfallStepContext
): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {
    // const bookingDetails = new BookingDetails();
    const userProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(stepContext.context, {});

    console.log('USER PROFILE ACT STEP', userProfile);

    switch (stepContext.result) {
        case 'Create New Job Order':
            return await stepContext.beginDialog('createJobOrderDialog');
            break;

        case 'Check Status':
            return await stepContext.beginDialog('checkJobOrderStatusDialog');
            break;

        case 'Chat with Team':
            userProfile.isHandover = true;
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(
                `Hi ${userProfile.user.first_name}, we're glad to assist you. Please type your concern below. A Podmachine associate will getback to you within 3-5 minutes. Thank you for your patience.`
            );

            await this.userProfileAccessor.set(stepContext.context, userProfile);

            return await stepContext.endDialog();
            break;

        case 'Upgrade Now':
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(
                `Redirecting to Upgrade Now page...`
            );

            return await stepContext.endDialog();
            break;

        case 'Schedule a Checkpoint Meeting':
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`Feature in progress...`);

            return await stepContext.endDialog();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return await stepContext.next();
    // return await stepContext.beginDialog('bookingDialog', bookingDetails);
}
```

I can see the saved user details in the introStep but when it comes to the actStep I no longer see the value and it comes out undefined. Can you help me with implementing UserState because I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly by loading it, the samples from github is not as clear.

```
USER PROFILE ACT STEP {}
[onTurnError] unhandled error: DialogContextError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')
```

Comment: Have you tried using the step dictionary to persist the value in the session? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt/src/dialogs/userProfileDialog.ts (e.g. stepContext.options.name = stepContext.result).

Comment: I'm hoping to do this as a last resort though. But I'm also planning to check the userState during the this.onMessage handler to check if the user is talking to an agent or not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your bot aren't storing the state, so it can't recover it on the next turn.

Are you setting somewhere the storage your bot are using?

Check this doc on how to use storages:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: It should be able to store it in MemoryStorage. Is there a problem on how I set and save the userState?

Comment: The way you are setting in the state accessor seems ok.  

Take a look on this simple bot doing same get and set operation:  
https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-js-bot-framework